# How does % in printf() works in this code fragment?(With respect to Turboc2 compiler)

Tags: c

```
main()
{  
 clrscr();  
 printf("%%%");  
 getch();  
}
```

The above code fragment prints only %% as output. How does this work internally?

Comment: It invokes undefined behaviour. See 7.21.6.1p9 in the standard.

Comment: I get only `%` as output

Comment: The first `%%` literally print `%`, then the single `%` with nothing to its right is not valid for `printf()`. That is probably why it just prints `%`, but this behavior is not defined in the standard. It can print `%%`, or it might aswell make your computer explode.

Comment: @ritlew: That's as valid as any other undefined behavior.

Comment: C# does not have `printf` - you may want to read on differences between C# and C++ at some point.

Answer (score 3):

`"%%"` is a valid format specifier. It prints the character `%`. `"%%%"`, however, is an invalid format. It invokes undefined behavior.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.